# Compile xcode project into a library file

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, static-libraries

I have two projects that are build on 2 different compilers. I need to combine both into one single app. Found out from a source that it is possible to compile any one of the project into a library and add it into the other to use it.

I fairly new this concept. Has any one done anything like this? How do i convert one of the project into a library and how would i connect the two? Will i still able to call the views in that project(library) in my other project? I am using XCODE 4.2 and iOS 5.

Answer (score 2):

Create a "Cocoa Touch Static Library" to build your "Project"/target, and include the then-built library (with its public headers) into the second one. Note that the details depend quite a bit on what you mean by "project" and by "call the views" (which looks a bit wrong).

If you have two existing projects (with .xcodeproj files), open the "app" project (guessing one is of such kind), and include the lib project inside it (by drag & drop, or by "Add Files..."). Not the opposite.

Then in the "Build Phases" of the app project, you can add your "lib" project as a target dependencies (making your lib to always build when building your app). Finally, add the lib project product (the .a) in the "Link" build phases of the "app" project.

Comment: I'm guessing he has two "App" projects.

Comment: @Cedric: Thanks for the info. Actually i have 3 .xcodeproj. One.xcodeproj have another.xcodeproj inside it. The other .xcodeproj is completely independent. What i have to do is convert the first .xcodeproj into a library file and add it into the second. What i meant by "call the views", is about calling the view controllers in the library files.

Comment: Again you cannot "convert" a .xcodeproj into a library. Be precise, and our help will be more focused. You can certainly have a project inside a Xcode window that contains 2 (or even X) other projects. Read Xcode4 documentation about "workspaces". Now, projects are just a collection of code, resources, config files and so on. You can a lot of different things with it. The things you "create" with this stuff are called "targets". And you can have library targets, or app targets in the same project etc. Anyway, I hope you start riding in the good direction.